# A problem in calculus

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=e^x-ax+a$, suppose there exist $x_1, x_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$, could we show that
\begin{equation*}
f'(\sqrt{x_1x_2})<0\ ?
\end{equation*}

Comment: Is this a math competition problem?

Comment: no, in fact I was asked by a friend, he is not in math.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The zero of $f$ occurs at the solution of 
$$e^x=a(1-x)$$
The solution is
$$x=1-W_n\left(\dfrac{e}{a}\right)$$
Where $W_n$ is the analytic continuation of the product log function, i.e., the Lambert $W$-function, and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. There is, however, only one solution, thus showing that $\sqrt{x_1x_2}=x_1=1-W_n\left(\dfrac{e}{a}\right)$. Then,
$$f^{'}\left(1-W_n\left(\dfrac{e}{a}\right)\right)=\exp\left(1-W_n\left(\dfrac{e}{a}\right)\right)-a$$
To show that this is lesser than zero, one has to show that 
$$1-\ln a<W_n\left(\dfrac{e}{a}\right)$$

Comment: is there a direct proof?

Comment: @user38600 Perhaps the mathworld wolfram page on the Lambert $W$-function would enlighten you.

Comment: I just don't think this problem is that hard to use the analytic continuation.

Comment: @user38600 This is my method of solving it. Any other methods would be awesome, too.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar. Are you sure that the argument of Lambert function should not be $-e/a$ instead of $e/a$ ?

Comment: Thank you all very much. I got a simple arugment which only uses direct computation of derivatives.

Comment: @user38600 Can you post your argument?

Comment: sure, I will post it soon.

Comment: @user38600 Did you forget to post it?